How to debug integration tests in typescript using Pycharm?
I am using PyCharm for coding in typescript. I can run npm run test:integration for running tests in the integration directory. However, I want to debug the tests.
The skeleton is:
my_project
 /src
 /tests
   /integration

I am using Jest for the tests. So I added a new Jest configuration, but it doesn't run with error

No tests found In ~/PycharmProjects/my_project/src

Although I put in the Test directory: ~/PycharmProjects/my_project/tests/integration
What should I config?

Do you have the professional version? A quick glance at the doc and I see that running and debugging tests are pay walled behind the professional version https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-jest.html

After installation, you need to configure Jest in PyCharm by going to run and Edit Configurations and following the steps in this link. Once configured, PyCharm should be able to locate and run your Jest integration tests correctly, allowing you to debug them as needed. You mentioned that you have already completed steps 1 to 3, so you can ignore those.
Here's a detailed step-by-step guide to creating a Jest run configuration in PyCharm for your integration tests rewritten from their website:
Step-by-Step Guide to Create a Jest Run Configuration

Open the Run/Debug Configuration Dialog:

Go to Run in the main menu.
Select Edit Configurations....


Add a New Jest Configuration:

Click the + button in the left-hand pane.
Select Jest from the list.


Specify the Node.js Interpreter:

Node Interpreter: Choose the Project alias to use the project default interpreter. PyCharm usually detects this automatically.
Alternatively, select another configured local or remote interpreter or click the Browse button to configure a new one.


Specify the Jest Package Location:

Jest Package: Point to the jest package. This is usually <your_project_root>/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js.


Set the Working Directory:

Working Directory: By default, this is set to the project root. If needed, change it to the desired folder, such as ~/PycharmProjects/my_project.


Specify the Tests to Run:

Tests: You can specify a specific test, a suite, an entire test file, or a folder with test files. For your case, it should be ~/PycharmProjects/my_project/tests/integration.


Optionally Specify the Jest Configuration File:

Configuration File: Optionally, specify the jest.config.js or jest.config.ts file. Click the Browse button to select the file or type the path directly.
If this field is empty, PyCharm will look for a package.json file with a jest key, or generate a Jest default configuration.


Optional Settings:

Jest Options: To enable watch mode, add the --watch flag.
Environment Variables: Specify environment variables if needed. These will be available in process.env.
Node Options: Add Node.js-specific command-line options, such as --inspect for debugging.



Example Jest Configuration
Here's an example setup for the Run/Debug Configuration: Jest dialog:

Node Interpreter: Project (automatically filled by PyCharm).
Jest Package: ~/PycharmProjects/my_project/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js.
Working Directory: ~/PycharmProjects/my_project.
Tests: ~/PycharmProjects/my_project/tests/integration.
Configuration File: ~/PycharmProjects/my_project/jest.config.js (if you have one).

Here is how to configure jest.config.js
Running and Debugging Tests

Select the Jest Configuration:

Choose your newly created Jest configuration from the dropdown in the top-right corner of PyCharm.


Run or Debug:

Click the Run or Debug button to start the tests.




Hey, thanks! I solve the problem by marking the Directory checkbox instead All tests
